# Is there a library or way to check the integrity of video files using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, video-processing

I know ffmepg can do this. But, I am developing a chrome extension having to check the integrity of video files.

Comment: See https://w3c.github.io/media-source/

Answer (score 0):

No. What I would do is port OpenCV plugins from FFmpeg and port it through JSNODE by setting up a .exe child process or something like that. Or have the video stream and have JavaScript check for timecode inconsistencies somehow.

Comment: _"No."_, _yes_ you can actually. You can load up binary data into typed arrays like `Int8Array` and then parse through it and create relevant object structures representing the different structures of the video file.   Then analyze those structures to see if they are valid. Wither or not it is efficient, reliable is a different matter.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think you are suggesting me to implement the validation myself using JS, right? :P

Comment: Yes he is... and you would be a hero if you implement this by using JS, go give it a try!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg This seems interesting. However, not sure whether it has implemented integrity checking. Will look into it when I have time.

Comment: that's seems like a solution to your problem, im checking it out

Comment: @LeroyThompson Sadly, it doesn't seem good enough nowadays since lots of issues that are not having a reply and it doesn't have integrity checking function. =_=

Answer (score 0):

As at Jan2020, I have have not found a native JS implementation.
But the following snippet works for me.

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var ff = new ffmpeg();

ff.on('start', function(commandLine) {
  // on start, you can verify the command line to be used
})
.on('progress', function(data) {
  // do something with progress data if you like
})
.on('end', function() {
  // do something when complete
})
.on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle error conditions
  // console.log('Error: ' + err.message)
  console.log('ffmpeg output:\n' + stdout)
  console.log('ffmpeg stderr:\n' + stderr)
})
// .addInput('path\to\file')
.addInput('.\\test\\corrupt_video.mp4')
.addInputOption('-xerror')
.addInputOption('-v error')
.output('-')
.outputOptions('-f null')
.run();
```